# How to Split total hours to regular and OT hours SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Query that grabs the Employees Name, Home Store, Payroll ID, and total hours worked. Below is the query:

```
 SELECT Employee_Tb.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb.Last_Name AS Name,
        Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id, Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, 
        SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) AS TotalHours
   FROM Employee_Tb
        INNER JOIN Payroll_Hours_Tb
              ON Employee_Tb.Employee_Id = Payroll_Hours_Tb.Employee_Id
  WHERE (Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
  GROUP BY Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, Employee_Tb.First_Name, Employee_Tb.Last_Name,
        Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
  ORDER BY Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
```

I'd like to split the Total hours into `"Regular Hours"` and `"OT Hours"`  Regular hours is defined as hours less than "40".  OT Hours is defined as greater than "40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a `CASE` expression for that, one for each value.

Instead of `SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked)`, you can do:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) > 40.0
    THEN 40.0
    ELSE SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked)
    END AS RegularHours,
CASE WHEN SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) > 40.0
    THEN SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) - 40.0
    ELSE 0.0
    END AS Overtime
```

The first `CASE` expression checks for a sum of hours greater than 40, and if found, locks in the regular hours at 40, otherwise uses the sum of hours (since it's less than 40).

The second `CASE` expression checks for a sum of hours greater than 40, and if found, subtracts 40 from the number of hours, to determine overtime.

Comment: Ignore the downvotes to the answer, they're just from petty users upset that I closed one of their off-topic questions.  Now if you have a legitimate complaint about my answer, I would be honestly interested in hearing about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
     SELECT Employee_Tb.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb.Last_Name AS Name,
            Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id, Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, 
            SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) AS TotalHours
       FROM Employee_Tb
            INNER JOIN Payroll_Hours_Tb
                    ON Employee_Tb.Employee_Id = Payroll_Hours_Tb.Employee_Id
      WHERE (Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
      GROUP BY Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, Employee_Tb.First_Name, Employee_Tb.Last_Name,
            Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
      ORDER BY Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
)
 SELECT Name, Home_Store_Id, Payroll_Id, TotalHours,
        CASE
             WHEN TotalHours <= 40 THEN TotalHours 
             ELSE 40
         END AS 'Regular',
        CASE
             WHEN TotalHours > 40 THEN TotalHours - 40
             ELSE 0
         END AS 'OT'
    FROM cte
```